# PHP Storm Debugging Creates Empty Server Definitions

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

Something seems to have broken in my PHP Storm IDE. When I try and debug using the listener, Storm loads the "Incoming connection from Xdebug" dialog but, the server name text field is empty. I can specify the file to debug but, nothing happens in the IDE. I can see that Storm is debugging the file in the stack trace but, it isn't mapping to the file in my IDE.

When I check the server configuration in Storm, it has created a nameless server definition. If I complete this definition, select it, and try debugging again, Storm just creates another empty server definition.

I have been successfully debugging with Storm for many years so I'm really unsure what has happened to cause this behaviour. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: **Web server software used?** But yes -- that field must be filled (it is a required field) .. so it *kind of* "makes sense" that it creates new one.

Comment: Nginx. The server name field is not actually editable when the dialog presents itself.

Comment: *"Nginx."* As suspected. You need to fix it on server config level. Basically, IDE checks the value of `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` (in PHP terms). Check this thread (last few posts) about how to: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5494835#5494835

Comment: *"The server name field is not actually editable when the dialog presents itself."* That is correct -- IDE only shows what it has detected. The only thing you could choose on such dialog is select correct mapping and click "OK" button. Everything else can be edited later in "Settings | PHP | Servers" if necessary.

Comment: There were already two working servers defined that Storm just started to ignore. If I complete the un-named server definition it creates and then call the web page again, Storm ignores the server definitions that are there and simply pops up another "Incoming connection" dialog and the cycle starts again. Do you know what triggers Storm to select a server definition? Thanks.

Comment: Value of "Host/Server Name" field. It has to have value (in both project config and during the debug request).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! It transpired that a system admin had completely removed the server_name declaration from the nginx .conf file. That's why my IDE just suddenly stopped working. After discussing with him why, it was re-added and now all works fine - phew! :)

Answer (score 13):

So .. your web server software is **nginx**.

**This issue must be fixed in nginx config file.** Thing is: nginx does not provide value for `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` (in PHP terms) which is used by PhpStorm to determine what config to use during debug.

Check this thread (last few posts) about how to fix it: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5494835#5494835

Something like `fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;` should do the job.

Comment: I agree that -- fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $hostname; -- according to the Nginx docs should work. However, I tried that and still nothing comes back for server name in PHP. I've re-specified server_name in the server block for now.

Comment: I also could only make it work within server block, but unfortunately its not dynamic. Meaning, I can't just change my Docker config for all projects. I would need to re-configure it for every project.

Comment: @RicardoMartins Try specifying the server name (for IDE purposes) via `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` environment variable (as part of the docker file config) e.g. `PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=reports.dev"` P.S. Should not the nginx config (specific for this site) be supplied from outside the container anyway?

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for replying. Amazing. In fact I just added it to the Docker-compose file as described here (https://www.arroyolabs.com/2016/10/docker-xdebug/) and as you said, it worked. It just has to match with PhpStorm "Server Name".

Answer (score 2):

i set a "server_name xxx.foo.com;" attribute in nginx configure file solve this problem