# Xdebug (inside Docker container) ignoring XDEBUG_CONFIG environment variable

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm running a PHP application on Docker and I'd like to debug it using XDebug.
In my docker-compose I added the following lines in the phpfpm part:

```
environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_enable=1 remote_host=192.168.110.29 remote_port=9000 idekey=PHPSTORM remote_autostart=1"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=reports.dev"
```

I configured PHPStorm in the right way, listening on port 9000 and ran the application.

The application works flawlessly but XDebug doesn't seem to be working.

If I move the lines of configuration inside the php.ini file the debugger works, except for the fact that Server Name is empty and I cannot debug (that's why I tried following the docker-compose configuration way).

If, inside the docker container, I run echo $XDEBUG_CONFIG the output is right, but XDebug seems not to read that Env variable.

Comment: 1) Are you serving/trying to debug web pages? If so -- configure server name there (especially if it's nginx -- quite often it is left blank). 2) How do you launch containers? I mean -- are you using PhpStorm for this or it's managed from outside (e.g. terminal)? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33800

Comment: 1) yes, I'm debugging web pages and yes, server name in nginx is not defined since the code is not inside a container so I have a single docker-compose for all of my projects and I'm not willing to change it.
2) I'm using docker-compose up in a terminal outside phpstorm.


BTW this does not answer my question, I cannot understand why XDEBUG_CONFIG is not being read by xdebug inside the container

Comment: For an empty server name, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362202/4200039 worked for me: `fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;` in the nginx config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. My image was based on [`nimmis/alpine-apache-php7/`](https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/alpine-apache-php7/). I found that the image was using [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/index.html) to start processes. `supervisor` has no knowledge of the Docker environment variables.

The convention to tell `supervisor` that a process needs to be run, is to create a `run` script at `/etc/sv/{process}/run`. [A script like this](https://github.com/nimmis/docker-alpine-apache/blob/master/root/etc/sv/apache2/run) was used to start Apache. I needed to change the script so that it would import Docker environment variables before starting Apache.

The [docs for the base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/alpine-micro/) explain the convention for importing Docker environment:

> If you need environment variables from the docker command line (-e,--env=[]) add
>
> `source /etc/envvars`
>
> before you use them in the script file

So I created [my own custom `run` script](https://github.com/Birch-san/birchlabs-blog-2/blob/56d7942ee78e54dafa895090bab13dc1e35ad542/dev-server/apache-run.sh#L17-L18) for Apache — I added `source /etc/envvars` just before execution of `httpd`.

I overwrote [the original `run` script](https://github.com/nimmis/docker-alpine-apache/blob/master/root/etc/sv/apache2/run), by adding a simple `COPY` to [my Dockerfile](https://github.com/Birch-san/birchlabs-blog-2/blob/56d7942ee78e54dafa895090bab13dc1e35ad542/dev-server/Dockerfile#L24):

```
COPY apache-run.sh /etc/sv/apache2/run
```

This successfully ensured that my `$XDEBUG_CONFIG` was visible to `httpd` at the time it was launched. I was able to confirm that this affected my PHP configuration, by printing `phpinfo();` in a webpage.

Answer (score 3):

Did you do a `phpinfo();`?  That should tell you the settings used.

I had the same problem... took me forever to figure out.   Are you using `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`?   If so remove that line.

My nginx proxy was forwarding an IP through (which was wrong) and so the ip set in XDEBUG_CONFIG was being ignored.

Comment: This is it (I am using docker container), thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a different problem using the official PHP-FPM-Alpine docker image (`FROM php:7-fpm-alpine`)

I needed to add the XDEBUG-CONFIG to the fpm pool config:

`env[XDEBUG_CONFIG] = $XDEBUG_CONFIG`

See full config https://github.com/attrib/docker-symfony