# Docker Environment Variables missing for PhpStorm Unit Testing

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, phpstorm

I am currently trying to set up a development environment with Docker. The goal is have a single Docker Compose file to start all necessary containers and develop and test code within the containers.

I now ran into a problem with my environment variables not being available when running tests using PhpStorm's built-in Docker support. All my tests are succeeding when running `docker compose exec api-internal-php vendor/bin/phpunit` but not when running my tests in PhpStorm. To clarify: In both cases I am executing my tests in the running container. The reason for my tests failing is that the environment variables I defined in my Docker Compose file, and that are necessary for connecting to my database, are not available when running PHPUnit in PhpStorm. My Docker image is based on php:8.2-fpm-alpine.

My system configuration (up-to-date at the time of writing):

- macOS 13.1
- Docker Desktop 4.15.0
- PhpStorm 2022.3.1

Of course I ensured that I am actually running the tests using Docker. I am using a Docker network and connect to the database by using the service's name. I can confirm that the scope of my environment variables is the issue, because when replacing the environment variables in my code by their actual value, the tests are succeeding even in PhpStorm. That also means that the test is able to connect to the database using the service's name and the Docker network.

I installed Xdebug in my image and debugging is working fine. By adding a breakpoint at the beginning of my test I can confirm that my variables are missing in the `$_ENV` array.

I tried different things and was searching for a solution for hours but did not succeed yet. I tried adding an fpm config file with my environment variables like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011630/21026760) suggested, which did not help. Otherwise, I did not find any question with the exact same problem.

Relevant excerpt of my Docker Compose file:

```yaml
api-internal-php:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    args:
      APP_ENV: dev
      SYMFONY_DIRECTORY: backend-api-internal
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - ./backend-api-internal:/var/www/html:ro
    - ./backend-api-internal/var:/var/www/html/var
    - ./backend-api-internal/vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
    - ./backend-api-internal/.phpunit.result.cache:/var/www/html/.phpunit.result.cache
  environment:
    DB_ANSWERS_URL: mysqli://root:local@mariadb/
    DB_DEV_NAME: dev_env_db
    DB_TEST_NAME: test_env_db
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
    - model
```

One interesting side note: My application/working directory in the container is (obviously) `/var/www/html`. Somehow, PhpStorm uses `/opt/project` as the path mapping. As I said, when replacing the environment variables in the code by their actual value, the tests run just fine, so I do not think that this is the problem.

Comment: It's not clear from your post if you run your tests during build or at run-time, but environment variables are only available at run-time.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. In both cases, I am executing the tests in my running container. I added that information to my question.

Comment: Did you try to setup your needed variables in phpunit.xml https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-env-element

Comment: You can also setup an bootstrap file https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html?highlight=bootstrap#the-bootstrap-attribute witch can be set in PHPStorm under _Use alternative bootrap file_

Comment: I would argue that this is similar to replacing the environment variables in the code. It is working when I place the actual value in the phpunit.xml file (value="test_env_db") but not when I try to get the variable from the environment (value="${DB_TEST_NAME}"). I could combine that with envsubst at build-time, but it is not the ideal solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the bootstrap file does not help, because the environment variables are not available at all when running tests in PhpStorm, including before running the tests in the bootstrap file.

Comment: You can set up $_ENV in that bootstrap file. So you can manually make them available. You can use something like https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv to parse the .env file.

Comment: As i know, PHPStorm uses an phpstrom_helpers container and that doesn't load the environment from the docker-compose file. Better setup your environment variables in a real .env file and not in the docker-compose.

Comment: I am indeed using symfony/dotenv. But I do not want to define the environment variables in a .env file of the project but in the Docker Compose file instead to be able to have different configurations for development and productions. There are many possible workarounds like using envsubst or copying .env files into the container during build-time. But the main problem that I am trying to understand is why container-specific environment variables are available when executing commands in the container with `docker compose exec` but not when running tests in that container with PhpStorm.

Comment: Lookup your CLI Interperters Setting. Under Lifecycle you can switch from run to exec. I thing its an Configuration issue in PHPStorm.

Comment: I also noticed the phpstorm_helpers containers and that's what I was guessing. But I feel like there should be another way than using .env files that have to be copied into the container. A way where environment variables can be transferred to that PhpStorm Helper container automatically

Comment: Thank you @Foobar! It was indeed a configuration issue and is solved now.

Comment: @hoelska *"It was indeed a configuration issue and is solved now."* Please post your solution as an answer (you can accept it later) -- it will help a lot other users in a similar situation. What was done and why (add a screenshot or two if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as it turned out, the Docker integration in PhpStorm works quite well if you know how to use it. The mistake I made was to first set up the CLI Interpreter as "Docker" instead of "Docker Compose" and then, when switching to "Docker Compose", not picking the correct "Lifecycle" option.

So first of all, to execute tests in your Docker container, go to the "PHP > CLI Interpreter" setting, click on the three dots and create a new one. Select "From Docker, ..." and then make sure to select "Docker Compose" if your setup is based on a Docker Compose configuration YAML file. There you can select your configuration file and the service. You do not need to set anything under "Environment Variables".

[image: Docker Compose PHP Interpreter]

Hit "OK" and then, lastly, to execute tests in a running container, change the "Lifecycle" setting to "Connect to existing container". Under the hood, this will use the `docker compose exec` command instead of `docker compose run`.

[image: Lifecycle Setting]

Thanks to **@Foobar** for the solution!